# How to toggle jqGrid display using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, show-hide

We have two jqGrid grids - we only want to display one at a time based on a user's input.

Each grid, when displayed, should appear on the screen at the same location.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Currently we just have our HTML set up with `<table id="list"></table>` and then we create the grid with `$("#list").jqGrid({...`.

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid create some divs over table and pager elemetes. The id of the div which contain all the jqGrid elements is a div with id="gbox_list" in your case.

So to hide the grid you cane use `$("#gbox_list").hide();` and to show it back: `$("#gbox_list").show();`. If you want to use another toggle effectes which you needs, but with the same `$("#gbox_list")` object.

Comment: Thanks.  We also have the pager using `<div id="pager">`..  what is the div name for the pager?  Also - can you "bind" two different grids to the same table and pager HTML elements and then unbind one and bind the other one to toggle the grids?

Comment: Or is that a dumb question regarding the pager?  Would we just do $("#pager").hide()?  So to do a toggle we'd hide both the table div and the pager div, then show the table and pager divs of the other grid?

Comment: @Marcus: the pager will be placed inside of the "gbox", so hiding of the `$("#gbox_list")` will hide also the corresponding pager (the pager used in the jqGrid definition. I am not sure that I understand correct what you mean with the "binding" two different grids to the same table. I recommand you not share any DOM elements between the grids. Hiding and showing is one way. Another way is removing of unneeded grid and full recreating another. You can a little play with different approatch and after that decide which it the best in your environment.

Comment: How do you remove a given grid and then recreate another grid?

Comment: @Marcus: You can do this in different ways. One way is the usage of `GridUnload` or `GridDestroy`(see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods). Another is placing of both the table and the pager div elements inside one an additional div: `<div id="main"><table id="list"></table><div id="pager"></div></div>` and then use just `$("#main").empty()` to destroy or `$("#main").html('<table id="list"></table><div id="pager"></div>')` to recreate the grid base elements. To make jqGrid from recreated table with the pager div you can use the same code as usual.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="click1">Toggle</a>
<table class="list" id="list1"></table>
<table class="list" id="list2" style="display: none;"></table>
```

JQuery:

```
$("a#click1").click(function() {
    $("table#list1").toggle();
    $("table#list2").toggle();
});
```

PS. I am wondering whether jqGrid will work on items that have `display: none` and are thus effectively removed from the DOM; if it doesnt work out you might want to adapt the toggle() function to use the visibility property instead.

```
$("table.list").toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).css({"visibility": "hidden"});
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css({"visibility: "visible"});
    }
);
```